# How to get search results in different boxes in html

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have this search engine that gets results based on a search query. I am new to html so I don't know how to manage to put the results in different result boxes.

So what happens is that all of the results overlap each other. How can I put them in separate boxes? Thank you for any suggestion.

This is my html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Ghibli Studio | People</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/species.css' %}">
   <style>
       @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class=" header">
   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
       <form action='/species' method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="search">


               <input type="text" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="    Type character name, gender, age, or eye color">
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
               <button type="submit" class="searchButton">

                   <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i>
               </button>

           </div>


       </form>


       {% if species %}
       {% for s in species %}
       <div>
           <h4>{{s.Name}}</h4>
           <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
               Classification: {{s.Classification}}
               <br>Eye color: {{ s.Eye_Colors }}
               <br>Hair color: {{s.Hair_Colors}}
           </h5>
       </div>
       {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
    background: url(https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1007358814/thumb/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.8);
}

.header {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/c/ca/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg/640px-Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png) no-repeat center;
    font-size: 14px;
    filter: invert(100%);
    width: 640px;
    height: 307px;
    background-size: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.search {
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    display: flex;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.searchTerm {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #dcddec;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2);
}

.searchTerm:focus {
    color: #ebeaef;
}

.searchButton {
    position: relative;
    top: -38px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px transparent;
    background: transparent;
    color: #ebeaef;
    margin-left: 328px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: #dedeef;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #666;
}



h4 {
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2),rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2));
    background-position: center;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    left: 38%;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: -30px;
    background: #F2F4F4;
    width: 20%;
    height: 140px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 38%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: Box results image]

Comment: You have one input in your form, so you receive one pair `name=value` as a POST string. How do you want to split it?

Comment: Oh, I am not sure what you mean with 'split it'. What I want is to get my results in different boxes instead of all piled up on top of each other.

Comment: Could you please, add a snippet how it is looks like? Seriously, I don't 'speak' python or django.... but fluent in html and css

Comment: Okay, I added a picture of how it looks like.

Comment: You could create a `<div>` outside the `if` with a specific class and in the `css` of that class you can put `.myClass { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap}` that would order the boxes you are creating and ordering them in a row format and if they overlap the width of the container they will start a new line. I created an example in another response.

Comment: @NicholasGoodingRios I am not sure why that doesn't seem to work either, maybe there's something wrong with my css.

Comment: In my answer you can see the `css`changes, the issue you are experiencing is because you are absolute positioning the name and data elements (the `h4` and `h5` elements), which should be relative positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't resist and thoroughly cleaned your site... I'm really devoted to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), so I deleted any external (monstrous and buggy ...) css. The only missing item is the magnifier - if you really need it, grab a free icon from the internet, without buggy code ...
It is absolutely mobile-first and pure. The only fixed size is the `section` width because you want them look the same. Test if is appropriate for mammals :). If results are of a  different length, the height may need to be determined too.
Top picture size is dependent of screen height - snippet window is oddly short.

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box}          /* added */
body{
font-family: Dosis, sans-serif;
background: #cae;           /* replaced rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.7); */
background: url(https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1007358814/thumb/1.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
}
header{
margin: 1vh auto;           /* replaced 5vh auto; */
                            /* moved into @media height: 35vh; */
max-width: 100vw;           /* added */
}
header img{
max-height: 100%;           /* replaced height: 100%; */
max-width: 100%;            /* replaced width: auto; */
}
input{
background: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2);
box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border: 1px solid #edf;
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 15px;
min-width: 30vw;            /* replaced 300px; */
max-width: 80vw;            /* replaced width: 30%; */
outline: 0;
margin: 1vh auto;           /* replaced 2vh auto; */
}
input:focus{
background: rgba(250,222,255, 0.9);
}
::placeholder{
color: #739;
}
[type=submit]{
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
outline: 0;
border: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.6);
}
h4{
background: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.6);
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
margin: 0 0 20px;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: #fff;
}
section{
max-width: 100vw;           /* replaced width: 300px; */
margin: 2vw auto;           /* added auto */
padding: 0 0 20px;
display: inline-block;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
border-radius: 10px;
color: #878;
}
section b{
color: #739;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
p{
margin: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 350px){
header{ margin: 5vh auto 2vh; height: 35vh}
header img{ height: 35vh}
input, section{ width: 300px; margin: 2vw}}
```

```html
<header><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/c/ca/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg" alt="logo"></header>
<form>
<input name="search" placeholder="Type character name, gender, age, or eye color" required>
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
<!--    {% if species %}
    {% for s in species %}
    <section>
    <h4>{{s.Name}}</h4>
    <p>Classification: <b>{{s.Classification}}</b></p>
    <p>Eye color: <b>{{ s.Eye_Colors }}</b></p>
    <p>Hair color: <b>{{s.Hair_Colors}}</b></p>
    </section>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} -->

<section><h4>Name</h4>
<p>Classification: <b>Mammal</b></p>
<p>Eye color: <b>grey</b></p>
<p>Hair color: <b>grey</b></p>
</section>
<section><h4>Name</h4>
<p>Classification: <b>Mammal</b></p>
<p>Eye color: <b>grey</b></p>
<p>Hair color: <b>grey</b></p>
</section>
<section><h4>Name</h4>
<p>Classification: <b>Mammal</b></p>
<p>Eye color: <b>grey</b></p>
<p>Hair color: <b>grey</b></p>
</section>
<section><h4>Name</h4>
<p>Classification: <b>Mammal</b></p>
<p>Eye color: <b>grey</b></p>
<p>Hair color: <b>grey</b></p>
</section>
<section><h4>Name</h4>
<p>Classification: <b>Mammal</b></p>
<p>Eye color: <b>grey</b></p>
<p>Hair color: <b>grey</b></p>
</section>
```

Comment: This is perfect! It works very well now. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: @fayewaii it was a pleasure

Comment: @fayewaii I discovered an issue on a slim device - I added all the annotated fixes to the snippet (css only) - now is perfect even for 120px width device :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed opening div tag after the {% for s in species %} line.  So for each s, you are opening a new div but never closing it.  So just move the closing div that is after the {% endif %} so that it is before the {% endfor %}.  I've corrected the html below:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ghibli Studio | People</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/species.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <form action='/species' method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Type character name, gender, age, or eye color">
                    <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        
            {% if species %}
                <ul>
                    {% for s in species %}
                        <li class="result">
                            <h4>{{ s.Name }}</h4>
                            <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
                                Classification: {{ s.Classification }} 
                                <br>Eye colors: {{ s.Eye_Colors }}
                                <br>Hair colors: {{ s.Hair_Colors }}
                            </h5>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I did several things here.  I moved the stylesheet links up to the head section.  They should not be embedded in the body.  I added li tags around the list items within the ul.  I fixed the unclosed divs, and I changed the wrapper div so that it now surrounds the form and the list of results, since I think that is probably what you were going for.  I also removed the redundant div that was surrounding the ul tag.

Comment: I changed my code editing things a bit but basically making it tidier, the thing is that the overlapping still occurs..

Answer (score 0):

They are overlapping because you have a closing `</div>` outside of your `if` statement while the opening `<div>` is inside. this causes the html to create new divs but never actually closes them.

EDIT: You could try using `li` elements inside of your 'ul' like the following

```
<ul class="result">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
    </style>

    <li>
        <h4>{{s.Name}}</h4>
        <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
            Classification: {{s.Classification}} 
            <br>Eye colors: {{ s.Eye_Colors }}
            <br>Hair colors: {{s.Hair_Colors}}
        </h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean and I did it, but it doesn't seem to change it... I changed the code to this so it'd be tidier and did that but the result is the same: ` {% if species %}
        {% for s in species %}
    <div>
        
        <h4>{{s.Name}}</h4>
        <h5 style="color:lightslategray;">
            Classification: {{s.Classification}}
            <br>Eye colors: {{ s.Eye_Colors }}
            <br>Hair colors: {{s.Hair_Colors}}
         </h5>
    </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} `

Comment: could it be because you are using a unordered list but not using list items? try the code in my answer!

Comment: Even with that answer sadly it doesn't work.. I took out the ul in my new modification but it still doesn't change it

Comment: I am not saying you should remove your `ul`, you need to enclose your `h4` and `h5` results with an `li` tag like I did in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I did what you said in your answer and it didn't work for some reason. I was just saying that I changed it afterwards but either way it does not work.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to incorporate the new changes you have made?

Answer (score 0):

Using @kloddant code I've created a snippet so you can check the outcome with my solution of putting all the elements inside the `if` and `for` on to an element with `css` properties. So let me explain step by step this possible solution.

#### 1. HTML Element structure

What we need to consider first is the order in which all HTML elements are going to be structured. This is, how do they relate to the page and other elements. In our example the basic structure you have is:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

to this structure you added two elements, the `header` and the `wrap`

```html
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
```

and inside the `wrap` is where the form and the results are shown.

The way all these elements interact with each other without any styling (this is without any `css` stylesheet or any `style=""` attribute inside the elements) is that they will be positioned as follows:

a. Parents on the back
b. Children on top
c. Siblings bellow the previous ones

#### 2. CSS style formatting

The second part to understand how `html` elements are structured, positioned and stiled is to review how `css` styling works. The `css` style adds additional properties to any `html` element, including visual properties such as the position in relation to other elements, the background, the color, the border; and, many more.

If you go through your `css` stylesheet, you will find out that you are using such properties to position the elements, paint them, padd them, and modify how the background looks.

So what we would first need to do is to check each element style properties and review the way you want them to look. For this you have as many possibilities as you could almost imagine, just look around this same forum and you'll find out great information. There are other great pages as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS) to learn more about `css`

In our particular case I changed some properties of the `html`, `body`, `.header` and `.wrap` elements to allow proper positioning so they look the way you see on the snippet. If you want to move the search bar to the top, move all elements inside `<form>` including it before the `<div class="order">` element that is before. Remember that sibling normally display below each other, so in this case is just enough to change their position in the `html`code.

#### 3. JavaScript

This part is not important now, but JavaScript allows you to interact with the `html` code during the whole process of request, response, load, render, etc. [Here you can have a better understanding of what it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). In our issue we are only using it to replicate what your `python` code will do when getting the information from the DB. You can omit it and just make sure you change the code that I have commented.

#### 4. The issue on hand

In your code what you will first need to do is to review the `html` without the `css` so you can verify how they position without any specific style. You will see how they are positioned from back to front, up-down.

Once you see how they relate start inputting the `css` style attributes on to each element so you can visually understand how they change. I recommend to specially review attributes such as:

```css
element {
    position: ;
    top: ;
    bottom: ;
    left: ;
    right: ;
    display: ;
}
```

this attributes will change the way all elements relate to each other, feel and look. Play with them some time so you can learn more than what I can just tell you.

So here is the snippet with the example of what you are trying to achieve. It has the search bar (form) below the response elements (you already know how to change that order). It has the `css` styling closest to your desired output (this is really the only thing you need to play with to change the background, the size, the place, the colors, etc. as what you mentioned in one comment). And finally it has the emulated `python` code that creates several demo elements.

```js
// This is just to create the demo elements that your 
// python code will create for you
var parent = $('.order');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  parent.append('<div class="result"><h4 class="name">Name' + i + '</h4><h5 class="data"  style="color:lightslategray;">                           Classification: ' + i + '<br>Eye colors: ' + i + '<br>Hair colors: ' + i + '</h5></div>');
}
```

```css
`enter code here`    /* This stylesheet is a synthesis between the one you had and the changes 
I made to be able to create the closest look to your desired output.
Review the differences to create your output */

html {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #666;
}

body {
  background: url(https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1007358814/thumb/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/c/ca/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg/640px-Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png) no-repeat center;
  filter: invert(100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 307px;
  background-size: 70%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.order {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.result {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#form {
  position: relative;
}

.search {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  display: flex;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #dcddec;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2);
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #ebeaef;
}

.searchButton {
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 2px transparent;
  background: transparent;
  color: #ebeaef;
  margin-left: 328px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #dedeef;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.name {
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2), rgba(140, 35, 207, 0.2));
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: #000000;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.data {
  height: 140px;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #F2F4F4;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--- THIS IS A COMMENT: Do not mind this line, is just to create the demo elements with the javascript. You need to remove it on your page --->
<!--- {% load static %} REMEMBER TO UNCOMMENT ALL LINES WITH THIS FORM SO YOUR CODE WORKS FINE --->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ghibli Studio | People</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/species.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="order">
      <!--- Added div --->
      <!--- I HAVE COMMENTED THIS CODE SO IT DOES NOT CONFLICT WITH THE DEMO ELEMENTS BUT YOU WILL NEED TO UNCOMMENT IT TO MAKE YOUR CODE WORK
              {% if species %}
                {% for s in species %}
                  <div class="result">
                    <h4 class="name">{{ s.Name }}</h4>
                    <h5 class="data" style="color:lightslategray;">Classification: {{ s.Classification }}<br>Eye colors: {{ s.Eye_Colors }}<br>Hair colors: {{ s.Hair_Colors }}
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              {% endif %} --->
    </div>
    <form id="form" action='/species' method="POST">
      <!--- {% csrf_token %} --->
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Type character name, gender, age, or eye color">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                    </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the code. I am confused about the first part with the var parent since from what I can see it's jQuery and I am not familiar with it. Should it go in the html file? Also, the result in your example seems to return the results on top of the search bar for some reason, as well as making the header image and the bar itself too big, so I am a bit worried about that. Thank you again, though, your comment is useful.

Comment: @fayewaii really do not worry about the javascript part and the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` tag as they are only meant to emulate what your python code does when getting the names and info of every movie. that is between the `{% if species %}` part of the code. If you look at my example I have commented your part and the javascript just emulates it to create the same structure you have.

Comment: To explain further, what the javascript or JQuery part does is that it gets the element that has a class named `order` with the function `$('.order')`. In javascript the element `$` is like a variable that allows you to use the functionalities of JQuery, including getting document (DOM) elements. JQuery function `$('slector')` is a transformation of fucntion `document.querySelectorAll('selector')`. What it allows you to do, is to get the element according to the chosen selector ([check it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

Comment: Finally i'm updating the answer to provide full responses to the rest of the inquires and specially those related to element positioning.

Comment: Oh, I undertand now! Thank you for explaining again!